# What do animals say in classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, idiom, animals, onomatopoeia

It is well known that the way animals "speak" is amusingly different in different languages.
(See lion below.)
This makes it hard to guess what kinds of words the Romans would have put in the mouths of various animals.
Are there attested animal sounds in classical Latin literature?

I am interested in all animals, but if you think this is too broad (if numerous animal sounds are known and scattered all over the extant literature), I can narrow it down.

Notice that I am not looking for verbs corresponding to animal sounds (barking, hissing, roaring and so on), but for "direct quotes from animals".
A collection of relevant verbs can be found [here](http://www.curculio.org/animalia.html), and online dictionaries can probably be used to compile more thorough ones.

[image: Lion roaring in various languages.]

Comment: @Rafael, the same happens in every language I guess. That is why I wanted to make it clear that I'm looking for the actual animal sounds (like *mur*, *grr* and *räyh* for a lion in Finnish) instead of verbs.

Comment: Norwegian: Brøl! (or if you like: Brøøøl!).  It's also the verb: "Løven brøler." (The lion roars)

Comment: On pages 3 and 4 (= folio 2) of the *Orbis Sensualium Pictus* by Comenius, he gives sounds for animals that appear to be Latin (because the English sounds that we know are quite different), though not classical. Unless they're Czech. https://archive.org/stream/johamoscommeniio00come#page/2/mode/2up

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, the verbs have survived much better in writing than the actual onomatopoeia. A few of these are fairly clearly based on the sound: *baubor* "bark", *hinnio* "whinny", *ululo* "howl" (and *ulula* "owl"), *mugio* "moo", *crocio* "croak". See [Suetonius, *De Naturis Animantium*](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/Chronologia/Lspost02/Suetonius/sue_anim.html) for a long list of these.

As far as directly transcribing animal sounds, only a few examples are listed in the dictionaries I've found:

- [*cocococo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0062%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DO%3Aentry%20group%3D4%3Aentry%3Donomatopoeia-harpers) — rooster crowing
- [*bee*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0062%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DO%3Aentry%20group%3D4%3Aentry%3Donomatopoeia-harpers) — sheep bleating
- <strike>[*hinni*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=hinnio) — horse whinnying (also listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias#Horse_whinnying))</strike> *debatable*

A few more for Greek are listed in the LSJ:

- [*βαά/baá*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dbau%2Fzw) — dog barking
- [*βῆ/bẽ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dbh%3D) — sheep bleating (as *bee* above)
- [*γρῦ/grũ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dgru%3D) — pig grunting (compare Latin *grunnio*, "grunt")
- [*ἀρρα/arra*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)ra%2Fzw) — dog growling
- [*μῦ/mũ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dmu%2Fzw1) — cow mooing
- [*υ/hu*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Du)u%2Fzw) — owl hooting

These were likely similar between Latin and Greek, but I can't find solid evidence of them being used in Latin.

There is also the famous [*brekekekèx koàx koáx*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dkoa%2Fc) from Aristophanes' [*Frogs*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Aristoph.%20Frogs%20230) ([translations](http://ronsen.org/monkminkpinkpunk/20/frogs.html)), which is still occasionally used in English nowadays. But I've only heard it as a reference to the *Frogs*, not because it sounds much like an actual frog.

Comment: Would you mind giving a better idea of the sources you use for this?  Definitely sounds plausible.

Comment: Added more links. Should have done that at the beginning!

Comment: Is it true that _βῆ_ was the only/main clue to tell which e (eta, epsilon) was long and short in classic Greek?

Comment: @Rafael I haven't heard that one; I believe the pronunciations were guessed at first based on poetic meters and Attic vowel contractions (ε+ε=ει, ε+α=η).

However, βῆ was important in tracing the history of β: in later Greek beta was (and is) pronounced more like English "v", but Aristophanes uses *βῆ βῆ* extensively for the sound of sheep. So we know that when Aristophanes' plays were being transcribed, β was more like a "b" than a "v".

Comment: Good answer! Are you sure *hinni* is what a horse says? It's only an unsourced Wikipedia mention. The other link, the dictionary entry on *hinnire*, says nothing about transcribing horse sounds although the verb is onomatopoetic.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Unfortunately I have no solid source for that one. I was taught that the word *hinnus* (mule) was derived from the sound, but if so it was likely through *hinnio*.

Comment: Came just for Βρεκεκεκὲξ κοὰξ κοάξ and was not disappointed.

Comment: Da hell! _brekekeke_ is what a frog says when it speaks Czech! I had no idea our frogs learnt it in Greece! Now, my life is complete.

Answer (score 6):

Three examples I have just now come across (*edit* make that four examples - see "owl" below):

**Donkey**

Lucius, having been turned into a donkey tries to draw attention to his plight, by calling upon the name of Caesar:

> *Et “O” quidem tantum disertum ac validum clamitavi, reliquum autem
>   Caesaris nomen enuntiare non potui.*
>
> And indeed I shouted “**O**” by itself eloquently and vigorously, but
>   I could not pronounce the rest of Caesar’s name.

Apuleius, *Metamorphoses*, 3.29

Later (7.3), wanting to clear his name for some crime committed while still a human, he tries to call out again:

> *... volui dicere: “Non feci.” Et verbum quidem praecedens semel ac
>   saepius immodice clamitavi, sequens vero nullo pacto disserere potui,
>   sed in prima remansi voce et identidem boavi “**Non non**” ...*
>
> I wanted to say: "I didn't do it."  And although I shouted the first
>   word over and over again, without restraint, I simply could not
>   pronounce the second word, but I was stuck on that first word and
>   brayed again and again, “Non . . . non . . ."

Which I can't help pronouncing the French, nasally way, to imitate what I (an English speaker) think a donkey sounds like.

**Dog**

> *... cum dicit - ‘**r**’; non multum est hoc cacosyntheton atque canina si lingua dico; nihil ad me; nomen enim illi est.*
>
> ... when he says - "r"; it does not make much difference if I speak this
>   in an [incorrect connection of words](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=cacosyntheton&la=la#lexicon) and in dog-language; it's nothing to me; because
>   that's its name.

Lucilius, *Satires*, 9:389–9

To be honest, I'm not sure what this is about but clearly "rrrrr" sounds like a dog to the writer (an angry one, I imagine!).

**Owl**

Varro gives the following onomatopoeic etymology for the "night owl", *noctua*:

> *quod **noctu** canit et vigilat*
>
> because it sings 'noctu' ('at night') and stays up overnight

*On the Latin Language*, 5.11.76