# "Nequidquam seros exercet noctua cantus": what is the Latin onomatopoeia for the owl's hoot?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, grammar-identification, animals, onomatopoeia

In the 16th century, *Robert et Antoine Lechevallier d'[Aigneaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famille_d%27Aigneaux)* made a famous translation of Virgil's *Aeneid* which was seemingly praised in the French world; they also translated the [*Georgics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgics) including this segment:

> At nebulæ magis ima petunt, campoque recumbunt;
>  Solis et occasum
>   servans de culmine summo
>  Nequidquam seros exercet **noctua
>   cantus**.
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>[ Et observant le temps que panche vers sa couche
>  Le soleil
>   abaissé, son nocturne **hou, hou**
>  Du haut d'un toit chaumeux
>   n'entonne le **Hibou**. ]</sup>
>
> [ Virgil, *Georgics*, [Latin](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Georgicon/Liber_I) (*Wikisource*), [translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=SQxwDb0TUNcC&dq=d'aigneaux%20virgile%20eneide&hl=fr&pg=PT139#v=onepage&q=hou&f=false) from d'Aigneaux (1582) and my quick transcription and use of bold. I, 401-403 ]

Actually one [attributes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/houhou) to this very translation the first [onomatopoeic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) use of *houhou* (similar to the *oo* sound in *hoot* in English, twice) in French to represent the owl's hoot ([more](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22162) on *hou*, pronounced [u] in Fr.). Needless to say, *[noctua](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=noctua) [cantus](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=cantus)*, the *owl's chant* I guess, doesn't contain any onomatopoeia.

---

- In Latin, what is, and how would you write, the sequence of onomatopoeia used to represent the cry a type of bird such as the owl makes? Do we have a well-known example from the classics or from that era?
- Could you please briefly analyze (cases, tenses, syntax) and explain
  the *nequidquam seros exercet noctua cantus* segment; in particular, what word is *seros* and what's its function; is *exercet* a passive verb 3SG; word for word is that something like: *uselessly [seros] is done the owl's chant*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do animals say in classical Latin?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/what-do-animals-say-in-classical-latin)

Comment: Since this is a more specific question, asking for details that we wouldn't expect to be covered in answers to the other question, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Romans didn't write out onomatopoeia very often, at least not in works which have survived. I'm not aware of any source which actually writes out the sound of an owl's call directly. We do, however, have records of onomatopoeic verbs for some of these sounds. (The equivalent of "howl" instead of "awooooooo" in English.)

The most descriptive verbs I've found for an owl's cry are

- [*ululō, -āre*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=ululo) (*ulula, -æ* = screech-owl)
- [*tūtubō, -āre*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=tutubo)
- [*būbulō, -āre*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=bubulo) (*būbo, -ōnis* = horned owl)
- [*strizō*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=strix1) (Greek verb; Lat. *strix, -igis* = screech-owl, archaic)

Greek also includes the more descriptive [*hūhūzō*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Du)u%2Fzw), but nothing of the sort is recorded in Latin sources.

For your second question, I'd give

> *Nequidquam seros exercet noctua cantus*
>   uselessly-ADV late-M-PL-ACC strive-3-SG-PRES-ACT-IND owl-F-SG-NOM songs-M-PL-ACC
>   "the owl toils fruitlessly at her nighttime songs"

- *Serus* is an adjective meaning "late", here in the masculine plural accusative to modify *cantūs*. In this case, probably better translated as "evening" or "night-time".
- *Cantus* itself is fourth-declension, not second, so *-ūs* is the accusative plural. (The perils of omitting macrons.)
- *Exercet* is active, with *noctua* as subject.